# error on android with robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I am new to android development. Learning best testing practices. I downloaded Robolectric 2.2. I wrote a simple test for the Spinner example that ships with android. I get an exception. I followed the steps on robolectric to set it up in eclipse. Thanks for your help.

Test code:

```
package com.example;

import com.android.example.spinner.R;
import com.android.example.spinner.SpinnerActivity;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;

import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import junit.framework.Assert;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class SpinnerActivityTest {
    private static final String tag = "SpinnerActivityTest";

    @Test
    public void spinnerShouldHaveOnClickListener() throws Exception {
        SpinnerActivity spinnerActivity = new SpinnerActivity();

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)spinnerActivity.findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
        OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = spinner.getOnItemClickListener();
        Assert.assertTrue(onItemClickListener != null);
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createRobolectricClassLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:144)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createSdkEnvironment(RobolectricTestRunner.java:116)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$3.create(RobolectricTestRunner.java:279)
    at org.robolectric.EnvHolder.getSdkEnvironment(EnvHolder.java:21)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getEnvironment(RobolectricTestRunner.java:277)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.access$100(RobolectricTestRunner.java:57)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:175)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

Since Robolectric 2 you have to start your activity with Robolectric.buildActivity():

```
Activity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity( SpinnerActivity.class ).attach().create().start().resume().visible().get();
```

For more info see here: http://robolectric.org/activity-lifecycle.html